# How to make DOM of parent component responsive when child component is loading in react 17

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx

I have a parent component with a textbox, and that contains another child component Tree, The child tree component takes a tree data structure and recursively creates a `<ui> <li>` tags out of the each children from the node of the tree. The tree component has another nested same Tree component within itself.

When the user types a text in the textbox i am rebuilding the tree based on search criteria and this tree data is being passed as a property to the child Tree component. Now when the tree has more than 20000 nodes including all the parent and their children, so the child component needs to render 20k `<li>` elements in the DOM with each search input change.

This whole process is making my the textbox in parent component stuck after each character input when the result is too big for the tree data,
How do i keep the textbox in parent component responsive and while those `<li>` in child components are rerendering recursively.